# Can action creator be a class with action methods

Tags: reactjs, redux, reactjs-flux, redux-thunk

Generally in Redux (thunk), action creators are static methods. However I have a particular scenario where action creators need to make an async call to different endpoints. One way to do it would be to pass in a flag to determine which endpoint to go to:

```
function _getEndPoint(isHouse) {
  return isHouse ? 'house' : 'flat';
}

export function post(model, isHouse = false) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      types: [POST, POST_SUCCESS, POST_FAILED],
      promise: (client) => client.post(`${_getEndPoint(isHouse)}`, {
        data: model,
      }),
    });
  };
}
```

But is there a way to create a class say `Property` with `post` as a public method which serves as action method. So when I instantiate the `Property` class, I define the type of the property and set the right endpoint on creation?

Coming from a C# background, I was also wondering if I can use something like Generics or inheritance to solve this problem.

Also, is this a good practice to attempt create action methods with classes as I read that Redux is more into functional style of programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to make calls to different endpoints (asynchronously or not) – these are different actions. Say you want to handle error. Generic type `POST_FAILED` will not tell you which resource has failed. What if you want to change state tree based on it? What if different types should be handled in various ways? Functional approach `POST_OF_SOMETHING_FAILED` suits better here. Small functions do their small things. Otherwise you would have to use complex `if` block.

Instead of using classes and inheritance you could implement some kind of action generator to get rid of code duplication. For example if you want to create shared CRUD actions, this is how create action might look like:

*/actions/generators/create.js*

```js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';


function requestCreateItem(modelName) {
  return {
    type: `CREATE_${modelName.toUpperCase()}_REQUEST`,
  };
}

function receiveCreateItem(modelName, item) {
  return {
    type: `CREATE_${modelName.toUpperCase()}_SUCCESS`,
    item,
    receivedAt: Date.now(),
  };
}

function catchCreateItemError(modelName, error) {
  return {
    type: `CREATE_${modelName.toUpperCase()}_ERROR`,
    error,
    receivedAt: Date.now(),
  };
}

function createItem(modelName) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestCreateItem(modelName));

    return fetch(`/${modelName}s`, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(json => {
      if (json.error) {
        dispatch(catchCreateItemError(modelName, json.error));
      } else {
        dispatch(receiveCreateItem(modelName, json));
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      dispatch(catchCreateItemError(modelName, error));
    });
  };
}


export default function create(modelName) {
  return () => createItem(modelName);
}
```

You can use it inside actions index file as a constructor.

*/actions/index.js*

```js
import create from './generators/create';
const createBot = create('bot');
export const botActions = { createBot };
```

This is the main idea.